# Won't insert into DATETIME field due to out of range value - has worked on 100's of other records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A query I have pasted below fails with this:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

It has inserted successfully for 100's of other records why is it erroring out with this particular one?

```
INSERT INTO [My].dbo.Table ([branch], [policyref], [receipt_email_received])
VALUES ('02', 'SCJY05PC01', '13/10/2015 13:46:00')
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to using a date format not supported by the current language, assuming that the `13` represents the day and not the month. The current date format is clearly `mm/dd/yyyy` but you are entering in a date in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```sql
SET LANGUAGE English;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/10/2015 13:46:00');
GO
-- The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
-- in an out-of-range value.

SET LANGUAGE Spanish;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/10/2015 13:46:00');
GO
-- 2015-10-13 13:46:00.000

SET LANGUAGE English;
```

It should also be mentioned that it is possible that the current language (and hence date format) is correct, but that in this one case, the "month" and "day" numbers got switched. It could be either by accident or if the data is coming from various sources and this source was one that uses the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Another option is to tell SQL Server what the format of the date-string is when you convert, regardless of current language (i.e. culture) setting:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE English;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/10/2015 13:46:00', 103);
-- 2015-10-13 13:46:00.000
```

But again, if the other dates you have entered so far come back correctly when you select them from the table, then it is probably just this one particular value that is off.

More info about style numbers (i.e. the `103`) here: [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: cheers, but why does it work perfectly fine for 100's of other records in the loop but fails on this particular one?

Comment: @Lynchie - did those 100s of other records all have dates belonging to the 12th or earlier of the month? And do you, in fact, now have lots of data you've inserted where the day and month have been swapped?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever correct they are all 12th or earlier of the month. My datetimes are all in the expected format.

Comment: @Lynchie - the problem is, any string of the form `pp/PP/yyyy`, where both `pp` and `PP` are values between 1 and 12 can be interpreted as *either* `dd/mm/yyyy` *or* `mm/dd/yyyy`. It's an ambiguous date format. You assumed it was interpreting it one way. It turns out it's interpreting it the other way.

Comment: @Lynchie That doesn't seem possible. Do you have a way to verify that any of those dates are correct? Could the `10` and the `13` in this one case have been swapped?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - seems you are bang on the money, if I change the code to SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/10/2015 13:46:00',103); I get the format I'm expecting I'm guessing because I'm converting it into 'English' correct?

Comment: @Lynchie The reason that works is due to you telling it what the incoming format is. Similar to what I showed but doesn't require changing a session-level setting. I will add that to my answer.